# Getting errors while submitting the form in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I am getting either of 2 errors one after the other.

While submitting the form either I get the error below

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

Or this error

> InvalidArgumentException
>
> Route [register/user/image] not defined.

I have cross checked everything unable to find out the real cause.

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('manage')->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|editor|member')->group(function() {
   Route::get('/', 'ManageController@index');
   Route::get('/carezone', 'ManageController@carezone')->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator')->name('manage.dashboard');
   Route::get('/dashboard', 'ManageController@dashboard')->name('manage.dashboard');
});


Route::middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|editor|member|subscriber')->group(function() {
  
   Route::get('register/user/details', 'RegisterUserController@showUserDetailsForm')->name('register.user.details');
   
   Route::post('register/user/details', 'RegisterUserController@postUserDetailsForm')->name('register.user.details');
   
   Route::get('/api/username/unique', 'RegisterUserController@apiCheckUniqueUserName')->name('api.username.unique');
   
   Route::get('register/user/image', 'RegisterUserController@showUserImageForm')->name('register.user.image');
 
   Route::post('register/user/image', 'RegisterUserController@postUserImageForm')->name('register.user.image');
});

   
Route::get('/email/unique', 'RegisterUserController@checkUniqueEmail')->name('email.unique');
  
Route::get('/get/city', 'RegisterUserController@ajaxGetCity')->name('get.city');

Route::get('/registration', 'RegisterUserController@showRegistrationForm')->name('registration');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**RegisterUserController.php**

```
       /*function to redirect user to user details page after register page*/
   public function showUserDetailsForm() {
      $states = State::all();
      return view('pages.registration.registerUserDetails', ['states'=> $states]);
   }

   /*function to post and save data to the database*/
   public function postUserDetailsForm(Request $request) {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
         'username' => 'required|alpha_num|min:6|max:20|unique:details,username',
         'dob'      => 'required|date',
         'gender'   => 'required|string',
         'state'    => 'required|numeric',//validation rule for max min values
         'city'     => 'required|numeric',//validation rule for max min values
      ]);

      $post = new Detail;
      $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
      $post->username = $request->username;
      $post->dob = $request->dob;
      $post->gender = $request->gender;
      $post->state_id = $request->state;
      $post->city_id = $request->city;
      $post->save();
      return redirect()->route('register/user/image');
   }
```

Small Portion Of my form

```
<form id="registerUserDetails" class="form-horizontal clearfix" method="POST" action="{{ route('register.user.details') }}" role="form" novalidate>
{{ csrf_field() }}
.
.
.
.
<button type="submit" class="tabButton">Next</button>
</form>
<script>Javascript Validation here</script>
```

Comment: which error do you have after doing the suggested changes by `it is all yours`?

Comment: @PeymanSeraj, I have not changed anything now as csrf was already included on my page and the route of the form is correct.

Comment: The *expired due to inactivity* error explains in an enough clear fashion the problem, and implies that your CSRF token has expired after a period of time. Most likely the page containing the form was kept open in the browser and submitted after the token had expired. That can be mitigated easiest by either increasing the session lifetime (if that is acceptable) or displaying a warning in the page if the token has expired (this can be done by the frontend checking with the server if the token in the page still matches the one in the session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the second error you must fix your route name on your controller method (and everywhere):

Actual:

```
return redirect()->route('register/user/image');
```

Correct:

```
return redirect()->route('register.user.image');
```

Comment: YA right, It was my bad and have fixed already but thanks that is the real problem.

Comment: what about the page expiration. Can you tell me how to increase expiration time?

Comment: Not sure the reason, but see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/session-lifetime-timeout-and-csrf-token-mismatch

Answer (score 1):

For solving the first error add the [csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf) field `{{ csrf_field() }}` to form

And for the second one, you route's name is **register.user.image**

so set the form's action like this

```
<form action=" {{ route('register.user.image') }} ">
```

Comment: csrf field is already added. the form is for register.user.details which on submit will redirect the user to register.user.image page but gives an error every time.